# Examine kernel module parameters programatically from Linux user space code?

Tags: c++, c, linux, kernel-module, spi

I'm working on writing code that uses linux' ioctl(...) functions to communicate with a SPI interface.

Recently I was trying to get up to our "typical" transfer use-case (roughly 500KB of bulk-transfer) and got handed an "errno 90" (EMSGSIZE) failure.  Digging into spidev.c, there's "bufsiz" set to a max of 4096 bytes in the transfer (or transfers).

I see the abiliy to change bufsiz by writing a new value to "/sys/module/spidev/parameters/bufsiz" and that's fine, but I doubt it'll let me expand that arbitrarily.

**But: is there any way to examine this parameter from my user-space code (outside of reading the above file)?**

So I need to be able to adapt my tx/rx code to whatever the current maximum buffer size is set to, whether my code's altered it or not, but that's pretty hard to do without being able to query the value from within my code.

Seems like there MUST be a simple way to get that value through some library call.

Comment: Next time, please add C#, Java and Go tags. They all have a similar syntax.

Comment: @Olaf: The `c` tag is appropriate because the driver is written in C, the `c++` tag is appropriate if Phil is writing C++ code, to let answerers know his preferred language for code samples.  Please don't randomly remove tags.

Comment: @BenVoigt: He should have state that. According to the file-extension. As given, the question is language-agnostic.

Comment: Files are the Linux/Unix way. Why not just read/write the sysfs files from your program? That way you don't need an API for everything.

Comment: @Olaf : Because I know nothing of C#, Java or Go (or Rust, or Cobol or Lisp, for that matter) to be aware that the syntax would be similar for this use case.

Comment: @PhilMills: Yes, programming by same syntax. Forget about the semantics. Great approach.

Comment: @Olaf: The Linux Way is often not very helpful.  Yes, it may be functional and it may be wonderfully general-purpose so that ANY language that can do file I/O can get the value... but in the majority of actual use cases, it kind of sucks because now the programmer has to open a file (and do validation on that) read a file (and do validation on that), convert a string to an int (and do validation on that) when it would have been about zero effort on the kernel module's developer's part to add a one-liner to the C/C++ header file that they're already creating to just return the damn value.

Comment: @PhilMills: That's why Linux is being use on most devices, worldwide. (wheras it is not the Linux, but the Unix way.) No one said not to wrap this into a library. If you do not like it, you should use a different system with an API to learn for every crap. As it looks, you should not rely on the buffer size anyway, as that is a matter of the hardware and the use of an OS is to abstract from this.

Comment: @PhilMills: And, no, it is not "a one-liner". Instead you have to care about access rights, etc. You have to reserve a syscall, changing the kernel-userspace interface, etc. All handled here with existing calls and permissions (basically). Feel free to complain to the kernel developers; I will not discuss this further, just do not program for Linux then; write your own OS (I did already). Until then: If you are in a country you have to follow its laws.